# Snapshot of one ES instance and restore on different ES instance

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am having two ES Instance running on a different machine, I have created the snapshot of my first ES instance and want to restore that snapshot on the second ES instance.

I followed the way stored the snapshot with same name in local storage.

But when I delete the backup folder of second instance and tried to copy past the content of first instance, the snapshot is deleted automatically in second Instance in kibana

Comment: May you please provide some details, like which instructions did you follow? Maybe these? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-register-repository.html It would be great if you could provide queries you executed. "tried to copy past the content " Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean here.